# Write selected columns in Excel to .txt file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am building an Excel add-in in Visual Studio and trying to write user-selected ranges of data to a text file. Users can select several (can be non-contiguous) ranges on a Windows Form. Addresses of the selected ranges are stored in a collection `rangesCollection`. So far I have tried to loop over the cells in these ranges, write cells in one big string and finally write the string to a .txt file:

> `Dim writefile As New StreamWriter(filePath & "data.txt")`
>   `dim sep, text, s as string`
>   `sep = ";"`
>   `for each ref in rangesCollection`
>         `srow = ""`
>         `for each cell in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.range(ref.Text)`
>               `srow = srow & cell.text & sep`
>         `next cell`
>         `s = s & vbCrLf & srow`
>   `next ref`
>   `writefile.write(s)`
>   `writefile.close()`

The solution becomes very slow on even slightly bigger datasets. For example, writing 3 columns of data each with a length of ~7500 cells takes about 15 seconds.

Can anyone help me with a quicker solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can save the file as a CSV.
the result is easily editable with a text editor program (or obviously programmatically).
it will write a text row for each row in the excel file separating the columns with a ';'

EXAMPLE (letters for the columns, numbers for the rows):

```
A1;B1
A2;
A3;B3
A4;B4
A5;B5
;B6
```

you can make a temp copy of your excel file and keep the original unedited, delete from the temp file the unselected cells and then save it as a CSV file.

Comment: I will give it a try as soon as I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem in a slightly different way. Found the solution here: [VB.NET/COM Server code way slower than Excel VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363171/vb-net-com-server-code-way-slower-than-excel-vba-code)

The problem before was looping over and by doing that accessing each cell, the solution is to write whole ranges to an array and work with its elements:

> `Dim writefile As New StreamWriter(filePath & "data.txt")`
>   `for each ref in rangesCollection`
>         `Dim values(colLength, 1) As Object`
>         `Dim ran As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.range(ref.text)`
>         `values = ran.value`
>         `for j=1 to colLength`
>               `writefile.Write(values(j, >1) & ";")`
>         `Next`
>         `writefile.Write(vbCrLf)`
>   `Next`
>   `writefile.close()`

It seems simple and basic, but maybe this code can help someone out in the future.