# Create Excel UDFs in VSTO managed code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Anyone have a complete example in VB.Net 2010 and different from this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pstubbs/archive/2004/12/31/344964.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx
[How to easily create an Excel UDF with VSTO Add-in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957575/how-to-easily-create-an-excel-udf-with-vsto-add-in-project)

Comment: What's wrong with the examples you've given? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

As explained the StackOverflow question you link to, [How to easily create an Excel UDF with VSTO Add-in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957575/how-to-easily-create-an-excel-udf-with-vsto-add-in-project), VSTO does not support the creation of UDFs for Excel. Alternatives for VB.NET are to make COM Automation add-ins as per your other links, or to use something like the free [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) library (which I develop).

The easiest way to make an Excel UDF with **Excel-DNA** is to:

- Create a new VB.NET Class Library project in Visual Studio.
- 'Install-Package Excel-DNA' from Nu-Get.
- Add a module with some code, compile and run.

Your first VB.NET function might look like this:

```
Imports ExcelDna.Integration
Public Module MyFunctions

    <ExcelFunction(Description:="My first .NET function")> _
    Public Function SayHello(name As String) As String
        Return "Hello " & name
    End Function

End Module
```

Then in Excel you enter the UDF as usual:

[image: Enter Formula]

and press 'Enter' to see the result:

[image: Hello World!]

A great guide to porting code from VBA to VB.NET with Excel-DNA is available from [Patrick O'Beirne](http://sysmod.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/migrating-an-excel-vba-add-in-to-a-vb-net-xll-with-excel-dna-update/).