# IsDate user defined function for vb.net excel interop

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

Following code is simplified version of `TnTinMn`'s code.

I also understand what this is doing: `values(i, 1) = DateTime.TryParse(CStr(obj).Trim, dt)`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    ws.Range("A1:A10000").Value2 = "Hello"
    ws.Range("A1").Value2 = "1/1/2000"
    ws.Range("A2").Value2 = "I am not a date"
    ws.Range("A3").Value2 = 100.123

    Dim values As Object(,) = CType(ws.Range("A1:A10000").Value, Object(,))

    For i As Integer = 1 To values.GetUpperBound(0)

        Dim typDate As Type = GetType(DateTime)
        Dim typString As Type = GetType(String)

        Dim obj As Object = values(i, 1)
        Dim typeOfObj As Type = obj.GetType

        Dim dt As DateTime

        If typeOfObj Is typDate Then
            values(i, 1) = True
        ElseIf typeOfObj Is typString Then
            values(i, 1) = DateTime.TryParse(CStr(obj).Trim, dt)
        Else
            values(i, 1) = False
        End If
    Next

    ws.Range("B1:B10000").Value = values
End Sub
```

Another version;

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    ws.Range("A1:A10000").Value2 = "Hello"
    ws.Range("A1").Value2 = "1/1/2000"
    ws.Range("A2").Value2 = "I am not a date"
    ws.Range("A3").Value2 = 100.123

    Dim values As Object(,) = CType(ws.Range("A1:A10000").Value, Object(,))

    For i = 1 To values.GetUpperBound(0)
        If IsDate(values(i, 1)) Then
            values(i, 1) = True
        Else
            values(i, 1) = False
        End If
    Next

    ws.Range("B1:B10000").Value = values
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont want to use following code because following code is very slow.
>
> ```
>    For i = 1 To 10000
>         If Not IsDate(WorkSheet1.Range("A" & i).Value.ToString) Then
>             WorkSheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = "FALSE"
>         End If
>    Next
> ```

Based on this statement, I am assuming that the `IsDate` function is not available to the Workbook.

When working with contiguous Excel ranges, it is best to pull the values into an array and process them.  You can also write a array to an identically sized Range.  Such reads and writes will be relatively quick.

The example below creates a new Workbook and writes out some data to Column A.  The `GetColumnA_SetColumnB` method is what you should focus on.  It retrieves the values in Column A and then processes them.  The code reuses the the array created by reading the values to hold the result of determining if the value is a valid DateTime.  Note that since the VBA IsDate function will evaluate a string that contains a valid date as True, such function is replicated in the method shown.

```
Private Const lastRow As Int32 = 10000

Private Sub demo()
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wb.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    CreateColumnA(ws)   ' creates some values to work with
    GetColumnA_SetColumnB(ws)
    ' leave excel open and in user control
    app.Visible = True
    app.UserControl = True
End Sub


Private Sub CreateColumnA(ws As Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim values As Object(,) = CType(Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Object), New Int32() {lastRow, 1}, New Int32() {1, 1}), Object(,))
    For i As Int32 = 1 To lastRow
        values(i, 1) = DateTime.Now()
    Next
    ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow.ToString).Value = values  ' set formatted values
    ws.Range("A1").Value2 = "  1/1/2000"    ' set a string that Vba.IsDate interprets as a Date
    ws.Range("A2").Value2 = "I am not a date"
    ws.Range("A3").Value2 = 100.123
    ws.Range("A3").ClearFormats()   ' make sure its formatted as a number
End Sub

Private Sub GetColumnA_SetColumnB(ws As Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim rngA As Excel.Range = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow.ToString)
    Dim rngB As Excel.Range = rngA.Offset(0, 1)

    Dim values As Object(,) = CType(rngA.Value, Object(,)) ' retrieve the formatted values

    Dim typDate As Type = GetType(DateTime)
    Dim typString As Type = GetType(String)

    For i As Int32 = 1 To values.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim obj As Object = values(i, 1)
        Dim typeOfObj As Type = obj.GetType

        If typeOfObj Is typDate Then
            values(i, 1) = True
        ElseIf typeOfObj Is typString Then
            ' it still may be a Date
            Dim dt As DateTime
            values(i, 1) = DateTime.TryParse(CStr(obj).Trim, dt)
        Else
            values(i, 1) = False
        End If
    Next
    ' write Column B
    rngB.Value = values
End Sub
```

Comment: @KenKeniee, that statement is evaluating whether or not a string value can be interpreted as a date value.  It is to replicate that same functionality of the VBA.IsDate function. In the VBA IDE immediate window, enter: `? VBA.IsDate("   1/1/2017   ")` and press the enter key.  It will evaluate to `True`.  The `DateTime.TryParse` is not as forgiving as the VBA IsDate  function in what it will accept as a valid date.  If you need more cases to evaluate as True, you will need to add that logic.

Comment: @KenKeniee,  LOL, I totally forgot about the compatibility IsDate function.  Yes, use that function.  It also handles the case where the retrieved object is Nothing (null) that I forgot to account for in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`DateTime.TryParse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Public Function IsDate(ByVal Input As String) As Boolean
    Return DateTime.TryParse(Input, Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: @KenKeniee : Don't think so. VBA and VSTO are two completely different things. VSTO is mainly for plugins that affect the program itself (new menus, toolbars, functions, etc.).

Comment: @KenKeniee : Such functions (called UDF) are not supported by default, but there are workarounds and helper libraries that'll make you able to use it like so. For instance there's ExcelDna: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957575/how-to-easily-create-an-excel-udf-with-vsto-add-in-project